# Using new operator in if statement condition a bad idea?

Tags: c#

```
if (!someList.Contains(new listItem(arg1, args2)))
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

For the code segment above, `someList` is a list of structs and `listItem` is the struct.

Does using the new operator in this context result in a memory leak? Or is this an example of bad practice in general? I have searched around on SO and Google, but wasn't able to find a question that specifically addressed this.

Comment: Unless you implement `Equals()`, that won't work.

Comment: @SLaks The code actually works, but why would you expect it not to?

Comment: @Keplah like he said: default object.equals will never match

Comment: @SLaks and @sehe It will work because `listItem` is a `struct` (text in OP)

Comment: Ah. Silly oversight. Sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to work really hard to create a memory leak in C#.  It's *possible*, but there are not very many cases where it happens accidentally (other than when inter-oping with other languages that don't have such straightforward memory management).  I won't go into the edge cases here though.

Here is what the memory will look like for that object:

- a local variable will be created in whatever method holds the code you've shown.  Since you didn't set the new structure to a local variable explicitly, it will have some name that can't be referenced in code.
- It will be passed, via the stack, to the method that you call.  (It will be passed by value, so there will now be two variables that have the same structure at this point).
- When `Contains` returns the parameters on it's call stack will be "freed", so we're now back to just having one variable.
- When the method you're currently in finishes (or possibly a bit earlier, if the compiler wants to optimize it knowing it's no longer used) the stack space of the structure will be "freed"

Even though the `new` keyword is used, the structure is not created on the heap.  It's still created on the stack.  In C# `new` is used when calling any constructor explicitly (barring reflection) and does not indicate an allocation on the heap (the way it does in, say, C++).

It's also worth mentioning that even if this were a class, and not a structure, it wouldn't result in any memory leak.  The object would end up on the heap, but the garbage collector will take care of cleaning it up at some point after it's no longer needed.  You're not doing anything here that would result in holding onto a reference to the object once it's not needed (and I know that `Contains` isn't going to do any shenanigans that would prevent it from being collected; if it was some unknown function it's possible but unlikely that they'd do something mean).

Answer (score 3):

That is not uncommon to have to do with structs. For instance, when working with `DateTime`s, it's a lot more readable to say:

```
if (fooDate == new DateTime(2000, 1, 30, 11, 30, 0))
```

than

```
if (fooDate.Year = 2000 && fooDate.Month = 1 && fooDate.Day = 30 && ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a memory leak, nor would I necessary call it bad style (it is used in the MSDN [example usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3))

But is probably not how I'd do it - I'd do something like:

```
if (!someList.Any(o => o.Arg1 == arg1 && o.Arg2 == arg2)) 
{ 
    // Do some stuff 
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this approach would be less efficient than the OP's approach.  It's also harder to read.  Why would you do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of readability. I find it harder to read when done like you have shown I prefer a separate declaration of the list

No difference in performance or memory leaks

Also when you declare a list separately you can give your list a meaningful name

E.g. var listOfDays = new List.....

Comment: Right, the code is just something I came up with on the fly. It's not being seriously implemented for an application.